# AWS Educate - Launch EC2 instance authorization issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am working on my school project and seeing permission issues using AWS Educate for students.

I am unable to launch EC2 instance (Spot instance). Read through the documentation about changing roles and policies to grant permission but it says my user is unauthorized to. Neither is it permitting to create a role - No permissions to change anything in IAM.
[image]

[image]

Also, since it's student access AWS doesn't provide support to raise a Case Request with them. I understand this is a redundant question but I tried the solutions provided but in vain due to student access limitations. To ask administrator to add permissions it just redirects me to documentation.

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I am under the impression that spot instances are not available through AWS Educate. You would need to use a regular account which is what you did apparently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this: The IAM user does not have permissions to do what you want. If you are the administrator, then you can assign (add) permissions to the user's attached policy. If you are not the administrator then you will need to contact that person for help.

Comment: Okay, I actually had to change from AWS Educate Starter account through third party quikLABS to an account that needed credit card details. I got free $150 credit and has full access to my account